# Use wildcard in @Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I use wildcard in `@Profile`?

For example:

```
@Profile("*-from-db")
private class Foo {
```

`Foo` bean should be activated when the `spring.profiles.active` is ended with `"-from-db"`; like dev-from-db, qa-from-db, prod-from-db, etc.

Comment: You cannot... Write your own rule which does that.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, this isn't possible using the `@Profile` annotation and can only be done by implementing your own `Condition`.

To do that, you need to create an annotation (eg. `@ConditionalOnProfileSuffix`) and create an implementation of `Condition` (the easiest way is by extending from [`SpringBootCondition`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/SpringBootCondition.html)).

After that you have to annotate your conditional annotation with the `@Conditional` annotation, for example:

```
@Conditional(OnProfileSuffixCondition.class)
```

Within `OnProfileSuffixCondition` (the implementation of `SpringBootCondition`), you can retrieve the active profiles by using:

```
conditionContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()
```

To retrieve the values from the annotation you can use:

```
annotatedTypeMetadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnProfileSuffix.class.getName());
```

This will return a `MultiValuedMap` where the key is the annotation property name, and the value is any object (depends on the type).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that with only @Profile annotation. You can try with conditional matchers.
Please check this post [Can I not (!) a collection of spring profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168881/can-i-not-a-collection-of-spring-profiles) and this one https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/using-spring-4-condition-to-control-bean-registration/. 
It should guide you to the right direction.