# Spring-Boot: @EnableRedisHttpSession annotation ignores profiles (when negating them)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I´m running into this weird issue with Spring Boot Profiles and `@EnableRedisHttpSession`:

If I use this setup, everything is correct:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"prod"})
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Neither `WebSecurity` nor `RedisSession` are initialized when running in other profiles than `prod`.

On the other hand, if I use "negated" profiles, both the security and redis logic are initialized:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"!dev", "!test"})
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I´m am doing this, since I want to run using custom profiles given from the outside.

I have tried several workarounds:

- For Security, I have disabled it by using this property: `security.ignored: /**`
- However, I am unable to disable the Redis Session. I have tried this:
  `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration`

  And this too: `spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false` but without success.

I am running Spring-Boot v1.5.16.RELEASE

*Edit*: This is the stacktrace shown when initializing Redis (which is not wanted in this profile):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException:     Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:348) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.13.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:249) ~[spring-session-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.fa
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done Spring in forever, but I did find this answer which suggests that you cannot "negate" profiles: [Can I negate (!) a collection of spring profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168881/can-i-negate-a-collection-of-spring-profiles)

Comment: Official documentation does not say so: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html What I don´t know whether the annotations are working fine when using it.

Comment: I tried the solution you have linked and indeed works. I wonder if we should report a bug to SpringBoot since the negation is clearly not working?