# How to inject dependency dynamically based on profile in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

Let's say I have below setup, one interface I have has one method `addTaxTrans()`:

```java
public interface TaxTransInterface {

    Response<Map<String, Object>> addTaxTrans(Long sessionId, TaxMap taxMap);

}
```

I have two classes implemented with this interface.

First impementation for `client1`

```java
@Component
public class Client1TaxImpl implements TaxTransInterface {

    @Override
    public Response<Map<String, Object>> addTaxTrans(Long sessionId, TaxMap taxMap) {
        // Common code + client 1 customization code
    }
}
```

Second implementation for client 2

```java
@Component
public class Client2TaxImpl implements TaxTransInterface {

    @Override
    public Response<Map<String, Object>> addTaxTrans(Long sessionId, TaxMap taxMap) {

        // Common code + Client 2 customization code
    }
}
```

Below is the service implementation, here I have autowired `TaxTransInterface` and calling `addTaxtrans` method:

```java
@Service
public class TaxSerImpl implements TaxSer {

    @Autowired
    private TaxTransInterface taxTransInterface;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Response<Map<String, Object>> addTax(TaxReq taxReq) {

        // Calling Trans Function
        return taxTransInterface.addTaxTrans(taxReq.getSessionId(), 
                        taxReq.getTaxMap());
    }
}
```

As of now I am not able to run the project getting below error:

```
Field taxTransInterface required a single bean, but 2 were found:
```

I know this error comes because two implementations I have for interface `TaxTransInterface`

So do we have any option like dynamically when I run application by below command for profile `client1`:

```sh
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=client1 sbill-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

then dynamically `Client1TaxImpl` should get inject and when run application for `client2` then `Client2TaxImpl` should get injected.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Just a thought !. Can I use strategy factory with `@Qualifier`? to handle above scenario.

Comment: Yes you can use qualifier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Annotate your `@Component` class with `@Profile("profilename")` so the component will be injected based on the profile.

Comment: Can i pass profile name dynamically instead of hardcoded profile name in @profile anotation ?

Comment: Since Spring 5.1 (incorporated in Spring Boot 2.1) you can also use logic operation like `profile("!dev")` see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63398808/3943054