# Spring Profiles issue for Multiprofile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Profiles doesnot works as expected. I have below two beans. First Bean I want to use for local, dev and myDevProfile. I added `@Profile({"local", "dev", "mydev"})`, but its not working. I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
@Qualifier("myApiClient")
public ApiClient localxApiClient() {
    return new RestTemplateApiClient(baseUrl);
}

@Bean
@Profile("!local")
@Qualifier("myApiClient")
public ApiClient xApiClient() {
    return new ComplexClient(baseUrl);
}
```

Comment: You show 2 identical beans

Comment: still both local and same qualifier

Comment: I am so sorry One is local and !local

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168881/can-i-negate-a-collection-of-spring-profiles

Comment: Nope this is not convenient in my case..

Comment: How are you activating the profile?

Comment: -Dspring.profiles.active=local

Comment: Can you post the whole class? That should work, the only way I can think it wouldn't is if you don't have the @Configuration annotation on the class. Also, how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class LocalApiClientTests {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    @Test
    public void testApiClient() {
        assertThat(apiClient).isInstanceOf(RestTemplateApiClient.class);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "mydev"})
public class NonLocalApiClientTests {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    @Test
    public void testApiClient() {
        assertThat(apiClient).isInstanceOf(ComplexClient.class);
    }
}
```