# How can I print the filter chain order list for Spring Webflux apps?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

As the title suggests, how can I print the filter list to debug the security chain list of webflux apps?

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140515/spring-security-where-can-i-find-the-list-of-all-security-filters-registered-w), it seems that I can set the log level to debug and it'll print the filter order for each request in the logs, which works perfect in a non-webflux application. I set mine through the JVM properties (example below):

```
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy=debug
```

However, when I tried to set the same JVM properties for my Webflux app, it doesn't show the security chain in the logs. Since the only different between the apps is the @EnableWebSecurity annotation (from @EnableWebFluxSecurity), I figure I need set the log level for a different class. Is it possible to set a log level for a different class to find the webflux security chain order? If so, which class can I set the debug level to in order to see the security chain?

Thank you!

Comment: I have run in to the same issue, an inspection of the source code for the 5.4.5 release of spring security in security/config/annotation/web/reactive shows no methods for adding a debug mode.  The @EnableWebSecurity and its debug messages are part of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter way of doing things